# App is increasing Memory when push/pop page (OnsenUI+Cordova+Angular)

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I'm using the OnsenUI (1.1.0) + Cordova (3.5.0) + Angular (1.2.21) for my App project.
In my tests, the app crashes on iOS.

So, I started to monitor that in XCode Memory/Performance Panel and I see that the memory is ever increased when it pop/puhsh Pages and sometimes it crashes. (I received a memory warnings too)

I monitored on Chrome Browser (in Windows)and the memory is increased too (but it doesn't crash)

I try the sample from OnsenUI site and the behavior is the same.

There is a workaround for this? Or, Do they have this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Anderson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for report. We are checking this issue. 
One problem is 'onClick' attribute which causes a Memory-leak. Please use addEventListener method.

Comment: Hi, I research from info and solution and I found this page: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3970

Comment: The Angular 1.2.x has problems!!!
I revert to 1.1.5 and works better, but I needed the new features from 1.2
So, I tried the 1.3.x (beta) and it works very well!!!